# Optimisation: multiple clickevents with same code but differten values

Tags: mouseclick-event

I have code below. Is ther a way to write this more efficiently? Because i repeat the code, there are only other values to the class Drank.

```
 private void btnCola_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Drank dranken = new Drank
        { Naam = "Cola", Prijs = 1.50M };
        lblDrankje.Content = dranken.ToString();
        GroupBox1.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnWater_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Drank dranken = new Drank
        { Naam = "Water", Prijs = 1.00M };
        lblDrankje.Content = dranken.ToString();
        GroupBox1.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnKoffie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Drank dranken = new Drank
        { Naam = "Koffie", Prijs = 1.70M };
        lblDrankje.Content = dranken.ToString();
        GroupBox1.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnSoep_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Drank dranken = new Drank
        { Naam = "Soep", Prijs = 1.90M };
        lblDrankje.Content = dranken.ToString();
        GroupBox1.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method with the logic for all click events

```
private void DrankClick(string naam, decimal prijs)
{
    Drank dranken = new Drank
    { Naam = naam, Prijs = prijs };
    lblDrankje.Content = dranken.ToString();
    GroupBox1.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

and then have a method for each event e.g.

```
private void btnCola_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DrankClick("Cola", 1.50M);
}
```